# Background needs to be different on sub-pages and product details page than index

Tags: css

I'm trying to manipulate the sub pages and prduct details page to only have a very small image across the top.  The look of the main "index" page is how I want that one to look.

Basically I want the image on the secondary pages to only show the top 300px of the image and the rest goes to the gray so you can see the products and wording against the solid gray color

current theme is Home iQ

thanks so much in advance

I've edited the theme css to get where i am now with the following code:

```
html {

background-color: #ebe9dc; 50% 0;
background-size: cover;
}

body {
width: 100%;
height: 750px;
background: url(http://www.sharkdigitalthinktank.com/images_pete/weed_background3.jpg)                      no-repeat center;
background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Please provide more information, specifically your HTML and more of your CSS. Providing a link to your page (if possible) or a JSFiddle would be extremely helpful.

Comment: thanks so much guys.. I got it fixed with your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a class on the body tag of the secondary pages, like so:

```
<body class="secondary">
//HTML
</body>
```

Then in your CSS add the following class after the other body class:

```
body.secondary {
  background-position: top;
  background-size: 100% 300px;
}
```

Is this what you are trying to do?

Comment: You're on the right track with using a `body class` to help control how much of an image is visible but I'm not understanding why you would shorten the page to do so like you have in your CSS.

Comment: @hungerstar Updated. I was just pulling from the main body class for the height.

Comment: I believe the problem with that solution is that image will get squeezed into the 300px of height. Rather than cropping it, see here: http://jsfiddle.net/85Ck3/.